# Is there a way to trace where my state file is being placed/referenced?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am using TF 0.11.11 on GCP.  I have my backend.tfvars file setup to store by state file in a GCP bucket:

```
# bucket where terraform state file will be kept
bucket = "this-is-my-tf-bucket"

# folder in the bucket where the terraform state file will be kept
prefix = "bucket.folder.sbx"

credentials = "greg-cred.json"
```

However, after I run my init and apply, I notice that the folder (bucket.folder.sbx) does not exist in my bucket.  The init and apply run fine, with no errors.  So I'm wondering...where is my state file going?

Is there a way to trace this?

As a secondary question, it seems that my local "terraform.tfstate" file is not getting placed in my .terraform directory and is getting placed into the root directory.  I'm wondering why this is?  How do you control where the local terraform.tfstate file is placed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is expected to have terraform.tfstate in a root directory of the project. 
According to Terrafor architecture, in folder .terraform should be installed modules and providers, but not the state file.

If you want to store a state file in GCP bucket - you need to declare a "terraform" block, see [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/types/gcs.html):

```
terraform {
  backend "gcs" {
    bucket  = "tf-state-prod"
    prefix  = "terraform/state"
  }
}
```

So, if you see terraform.tfstate locally - it's definatelly not in cloud. Terraform creates only one state file either locally, or in remote bucket (with configuration above).

Comment: It seems Terraform would stores state both locally and in the cloud, if cloud backend indicated.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a `backend.tfvars` does not create a backend configuration. More over, it is not even automatically loaded. More on that later.

To create a GCS remote backend configuration you should follow the [Terraform GCS backend documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/types/gcs.html):

```
terraform {
  backend "gcs" {
    # bucket where terraform state file will be kept
    bucket = "this-is-my-tf-bucket"
    # folder in the bucket where the terraform state file will be kept
    prefix = "bucket.folder.sbx"
    credentials = "greg-cred.json"
  }
}
```

If you do not provide a backend configuration, you get the default local backend and according to the [default backend documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/types/local.html#path) the state file path:

> defaults to "terraform.tfstate" relative to the root module by default.

As for the `backend.tfvars`, `*.tfvars` are not automatically loaded (except for `terraform.tfvars` or `*.auto.tfvars`). See the [input variables documentation](https://learn.hashicorp.com/terraform/getting-started/variables.html#from-a-file). If you want to load the the `backend.tfvars` file you should use `-var-file=backend.tfvars`. You must also reference these variables from your backend configuration. See this [example](https://github.com/monterail/terraform-bootstrap-example).